# SafeHandle with memory pressure

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, safehandle, constrained-execution-reg

The [`SafeHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle(v=vs.110).aspx) class allows the safe access to native resources under .NET with reference counting and cooperation from the P/Invoke marshaller to avoid premature disposal of handles that could lead to an application crash.

In some situation, it would be advantageous to notify the garbage collector that some native resource is using a lot of memory, for example, when the "handle" in question is a large buffer owned by a wrapped native library. The [`GC.AddMemoryPressure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.addmemorypressure(v=vs.110).aspx) may be used for this purpose; however, [`GC.RemoveMemoryPressure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.removememorypressure(v=vs.110).aspx) must be called at the end of the lifetime of the "handle".

The two approaches seem to be incompatible: `SafeHandle` is a `CriticalFinalizerObject` and its `ReleaseHandle` method runs in a Constrained Execution Region (CER). As `GC.RemoveMemoryPressure` has no `ReliabilityContractAttribute`, it must not be called from a CER (I guess at critical finalization time some parts of the GC concerned with memory pressure could be unavailable).

Two approaches came to my mind, both quite inelegant:

1. The SafeHandle could be wrapped into another object that has a non-critical finalizer (and Dispose method) that adds and removes the memory pressure. This has two deficiencies: firstly, someone could dispose the SafeHandle (it must be exposed to be passed to native methods) without disposing the wrapper, thus the memory pressure is overestimated. Secondly, the wrapper may become unreferenced while the SafeHandle is still alive, thus the memory pressure is underestimated (could be more severe).
2. The SafeHandle has a field of some non-critical finalizable type that manages the memory pressure. In this case, most problems from above are gone, however, the handle cannot dispose the memory pressure object in its Dispose or ReleaseHandle methods, as this would lead to a GC.RemoveMemoryPressure call in a CER. Another method (such as DisposeNoncriticial) could be provided, but this leads to a "slicing" issue when the handle is cast to IDisposable or used in a using block.

*Is there a common pattern to create a SafeHandle with associated memory pressure?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a nice pattern to wrap a handle and not expose it under normal circumstances. You could do that part just like `FileStream`. It is understood that the handle is owned by the `FileStream` and it is illegal to close it. This is not enforced but it's the contract.

The second issue is that you want to tie the lifetime of the `SafeHandle` to its wrapper. The `ConditionalWeakTable` class allows you to do that. The design would look like this:

```
class Wrapper {
 SafeHandle handle;
 CWT cwt = new CWT() { { handle, this } };

 ~Wrapper() { RemoveMemoryPressure(); }
}
```

The CWT keeps the wrapper alive iff the handle is alive. CWT is used to associate arbitrary state to non-extensible objects and not have any GC effect doing that.

I'm not sure all of this is worth it but it would be a solution to (mostly) satisfy your requirements.

Also, I'm not sure to what extent memory pressure is of practical use.

Comment: Neat, I did not think about this! My use-case is the storage of very large (> several gigabytes) arrays and passing them to a native linear algebra library that is also resposible for allocating and freeing them. I guess it couldn't hurt telling the CLR about these shenanigans...

Comment: I'm no expert on that but I don't know what it would do with that information. It does not know what object become dead at what point in time. It also does not know what object is associated with the memory pressure. There's a brief explanation in comutilnative.cpp but it should not apply to your case. The GC should never clean up any of these objects because you must deterministically dispose them. The finalizer should never be called in practice.

Comment: Interestingly, the `comutilnative.cpp` from CoreCLR basically always triggers the GC is the memory pressure exceeds 30% of the managed heap size. In my case, I guess it would be virtually always (when it matters), so maybe I could avoid losing sleep on memory pressure accounting and just profile whether calling GC.Collect() before huge allocations has any advantage.

Comment: If you maintain native memory and always correctly dispose it then the GC should have very little to do. Triggering it would not do anything. *If* you want to trigger you probably should trigger after dropping a lot of objects.